# Samba won't give file update notifications

Tags: centos7, samba

I cannot get file change notifications on my new installation of Samba and Centos 7.

I have two server clusters.  One running Centos 6.9 with an older Samba version (3.6.23) and the Second running Centos 7 with Samba version 4.6.2

With the first I can connect to the samba share using Windows 7 by mapping a network drive.  When the file is changed, I immediately see the update in my editor window.

With the second I connect using the same credentials in the same way but file updates are non-existent.  I have to close and re-open the file to see an changes that have been made.

This has been happening for several months and I make time to research this topic every couple of months I spend a few hours trying to fix it to no avail.  I've spent countless hours on both this site and google.

Here are the configurations and share information for the two different server clusters.

### Cluster 1:

```
uname -r:
2.6.32-696.13.2.el6.x86_64

lsb_release -a:
LSB Version:    :base-4.0-amd64:base-4.0-noarch:core-4.0-amd64:core-4.0-noarch:graphics-4.0-amd64:graphics-4.0-noarch:printing-4.0-amd64:printing-4.0-noarch
Distributor ID: CentOS
Description:    CentOS release 6.9 (Final)
Release:        6.9
Codename:       Final

smbstatus:
Samba version 3.6.23-45.el6_9
PID     Username      Group         Machine
-------------------------------------------------------------------
18490     user1         group1        comp1        (192.168.*.*)
21138     user2         user2         comp2        (192.168.*.*)
14315     user2         user2         comp3        (192.168.*.*)

Service      pid     machine       Connected at
-------------------------------------------------------
share1      18490   comp1       Wed Mar 21 09:59:20 2018
share2      14315   comp3       Tue Mar 20 10:07:59 2018
share3      14315   comp3       Tue Mar 20 10:07:59 2018
share2      21138   comp2       Tue Mar 20 10:24:53 2018

No locked files

smb.conf:
[global]
        workgroup = FSWD
        server string = Samba Server Version %v
        passdb backend = tdbsam
        guest account = apache
        cups options = raw

[websites]
        comment = Virtual Hosts
        path = /a/b/c
        read only = No
        create mask = 0644
        directory mask = 0755
```

### Cluster 2:

```
uname -r:
3.10.0-693.2.2.el7.x86_64

hostnamectl:
   Static hostname: srv.home.com
         Icon name: computer-vm
           Chassis: vm
        Machine ID: b8d0aff7632764daf448b26e28de2cd8
           Boot ID: 4548a3abbc356918b77ae462a058728d
    Virtualization: kvm
  Operating System: CentOS Linux 7 (Core)
       CPE OS Name: cpe:/o:centos:centos:7
            Kernel: Linux 3.10.0-693.2.2.el7.x86_64
      Architecture: x86-64

smbstatus:
Samba version 4.6.2
PID     Username     Group        Machine                                   Protocol Version  Encryption           Signing
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1218    user1        group1         192.168.0.1 (ipv4:192.168.0.1:49969)  SMB2_10           -                    -
1268    user1        group1         192.168.0.2 (ipv4:192.168.0.2:57232)  SMB3_11           -                    partial(AES-128-CMAC)

Service      pid     Machine       Connected at                     Encryption   Signing
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
share1      1268    192.168.0.2 Wed Mar 21 10:02:17 AM 2018 MDT  -            -
share2      1218    192.168.0.1 Wed Mar 21 09:59:20 AM 2018 MDT  -            -

Locked files:
Pid          Uid        DenyMode   Access      R/W        Oplock     SharePath   Name   Time
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1268         501        DENY_NONE  0x100081    RDONLY     NONE       /a/b/c     d/e/f       Wed Mar 21 10:10:46 2018
1268         501        DENY_NONE  0x100081    RDONLY     NONE       /a/b/c     d/e/f       Wed Mar 21 10:10:46 2018
1268         501        DENY_NONE  0x100081    RDONLY     NONE       /a/b/c     d/e/f       Wed Mar 21 10:12:09 2018
1268         501        DENY_NONE  0x100081    RDONLY     NONE       /a/b/c     .           Wed Mar 21 10:10:50 2018
1268         501        DENY_NONE  0x100081    RDONLY     NONE       /a/b/c     .           Wed Mar 21 10:12:09 2018
1268         501        DENY_NONE  0x100081    RDONLY     NONE       /a/b/c     d/e/f/logs  Wed Mar 21 10:10:45 2018
1268         501        DENY_NONE  0x100081    RDONLY     NONE       /a/b/c     d/e/f/logs  Wed Mar 21 10:10:46 2018
1268         501        DENY_NONE  0x100081    RDONLY     NONE       /a/b/c     d/e/f/logs  Wed Mar 21 10:12:09 2018
1268         501        DENY_NONE  0x100081    RDONLY     NONE       /a/b/c     d/e         Wed Mar 21 10:12:09 2018
1268         501        DENY_NONE  0x100081    RDONLY     NONE       /a/b/c     d           Wed Mar 21 10:12:09 2018
1218         501        DENY_ALL   0x100080    RDONLY     NONE       /          .           Wed Mar 21 09:59:43 2018

smb.conf:
[global]
    workgroup = MYCOMPANY
    server string = Samba Server Version %v
    guest account = apache
    log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
    max log size = 50
    security = user
    passdb backend = tdbsam
    load printers = yes
    cups options = raw

[homes]
    comment = Home Directories
    browseable = no
    writable = yes

[main]
    comment = Server Main
    valid users = user1
    path = /a/b/c
    read only = No
    writable = yes
    force group = group1
    create mask = 0664
    directory mask = 0775
```

Comment: 1. I decided to have another go at solving this problem as I was setting up new servers.  I tried suggestions of setting the protocol versions explicitly in the smb.conf, no joy.

2. I tried disabling the SMB2 cache by editing the registry and adding DirectoryCacheLifetime=0x00000000, FileInfoCacheLifetime=0x00000000, FileNotFoundCacheLifetime=0x00000000 to HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\LanmanWorkstation\Parameters, no joy.

Comment: I've switched to VSCode and noticed that on my Windows 7 machine file update notifications are actually working.  I've decided that this problem is specific to VS 2015 or the like, and also notepad++.  I guess some editors on Windows 7 just don't play nice with newer versions of Samba. :(  Oh well, I'm actually starting to like VSCode better than VS for the type of code I write anyway.